# getting Query with and

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have three tables 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeLM9.jpg)
 1- first personal information 
 2- second junction table ( which contains userid, languages, level )
 3- third languages which contains all languages

each person can speaks several languages. how can I get query that shows me people who can speak for example English and french?
the matter is all languages that one person can speak doesnt store in one cell
there are stored in different records (lines)
if I open third table(languages) in datasheet view.I have 100 languages here if I open plus sign beside each language I can see who speaks it.
when I want to get query-> in criteria part  "English" or "french"
I can see all peoples but if I changed or to and result is nothing?
is it possible to get query for people that can speak french and english ?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I've got an understanding of your table structure:

*Table:  **People***

- Person_ID: *AutoNumber* **Primary Key**
- PersonName: *Text*

*Table:  **Languages***

- Language_ID: *AutoNumber* **Primary Key**
- Language: *Text*

*Table:  **Person_Language_Link***

- Person_ID: *Number* **Primary Key**.  **Foreign Key** references *People*
- Language_ID: *Number* **Primary Key**.  **Foreign Key** references *Language*
- Language_Level: *Number*

`SELECT    PersonName
        , Language
        , Language_Level
FROM    (People T1 LEFT JOIN Person_Language_Link T2 ON T1.Person_ID = T2.Person_ID)
                   LEFT JOIN Languages T3 ON T2.Language_ID = T3.Language_ID
WHERE   Language IN ('French', 'English')`

As a graphic your query would look like this:
[image]

**Edit:**
After some thought this returns those people who know English and French, although I feel there's a better way to write the SQL:

```
SELECT        T2.PersonName
            , T4.Language
            , T3.Language_Level
FROM        (((
                SELECT        Person_ID
                            , Count(Person_ID) AS CountOfPerson_ID
                FROM        Person_Language_Link LEFT JOIN Languages ON Person_Language_Link.Language_ID = Languages.Language_ID
                WHERE       Languages.Language In ('French','English')
                GROUP BY    Person_ID
                HAVING      Count(Person_ID)=2
            ) T1 INNER JOIN People T2 ON T1.Person_ID = T2.Person_ID)
                 INNER JOIN Person_Language_Link T3 ON T1.Person_ID = T3.Person_ID)
                 INNER JOIN Languages T4 ON T3.Language_ID = T4.Language_ID
WHERE       T4.Language IN ('French','English')
```

The inner SELECT query returns the Person_ID of those that know both languages, the rest of the query then pulls the person name, language and level for those IDs.

Remove the final `WHERE` statement to see other languages that the people who speak French & English speak.

Comment: Hi, yes you got it correctly,
I tried what you said ,but It shows the peple that can spaek English or French.
it means one person speaks both languages and when I press run then it shows the name of this person two times one record in english, and one record for french . and also it shows person that just speak english and he cannot spaek french .I want to get query which shows people that can speak both languages (English and french) not (english or French)

Comment: I've updated to show a second query returning what you're asking.